# Convert ERPNext from Docker to regular install

Tags: docker, erpnext, frappe

I would like to install apps on my frappe bench installation. Unfortunately I used the Docker image to **install the ERPNext** bundle. I did not *realise* at the time that this setup does not allow the installation of additional apps.

What is the best way to convert my installation without losing my data?

My guess is a back-up and reinstall but I thought I would ask first in case there is an ideal installation process I should follow.

I have already configured **Traefik** to work with a custom certificate so I think I can leave that Docker container as is but I am open to sugestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Bare-bones version of the steps you need to follow should look like this:

1. Setup a bench identical to your dockerized setup - Here, you should ensure the apps are at the same commits or of the same versions.
2. Take a full backup of your site(s) along with the site config and files.
3. Restore this backup (with files) on a new site on the freshly created bench
4. Run the migrate command - to ensure any differences (if you have setup with newer versions of apps) are propagated to the site.

If you don't mind the downtime, I would turn on maintenance mode before step 2  and enable the new site directly.

Comment: Thank you Gavin! On this page it recommends installing Bench via containers: https://github.com/frappe/bench Is it possible to install apps on that system or should I slog through the manual install?

Answer (score 0):

There is a video tutorial about how to install apps using the docker image of erpnext: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3rwp-3UM_E. The video uses Windows, but I have successfully installed two erpnext servers using Debian, and added some apps to them with the explanations provided by the tutorial.

Here is their video to install ERPNext using the Docker image, which I found the easiest one around: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP8NpcvcIDk.

Also, if you lose your resources like icons or css sheets, because of installing some app, most probably you would need to rebuild frappe and erpnext apps so bench reinstall these resources:

bench build --app frappe --hard-link

bench build --app erpnext --hard-link

Hope this helps.